# Eclipse not able to pull or fetch a replaced tag from remote

Tags: eclipse, git

Another developer forced to replace an existing tag on the remote master branch. In Eclipse (Luna in my case), I could not get the updated tag, no matter by Team | Pull or by Team | Fetch from Upstream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found in Eclipse (Luna in my case) is:

1. Right click the project in the Project Explorer
2. Go to Team | Remote | Configure Fetch from Upstream...
3. In the Configure Fetch window, click button Advanced...
4. In the Annotated tags fetching strategy, change from option "Automatically follow tags if we fetch the thing they point at" to option "Always fetch tags, even if we do not have the thing it points at"
5. Click button Finish.

That's it. Now I can fetch the new updated tag.

Comment: In 2022-03 (4.23.0): View "Git Repositories" right click on the "fetch" remote (under "Remotes") then "Configure Fetch..." -> "Advanced" and select "Fetch all tags and their commits" (instead of "When fetching a commit, also fetch its tags)